# Perform join on two tables when values in one table may or may not be encloses in double quotes

Tags: sql

I have two tables

1.Employee Table

```
+-------+----------+-----------------+
| empno | empname  | deptname        |
+-------+----------+-----------------+
| 1     | Ross     | dept1_aniosbgis |
| 2     | Joey     | dept2_aswefbhjk |
| 3     | Chandler | dept3_xwukpgbtr |
| 4     | Monica   | dept1_aniosbgis |
| 5     | Phoebe   | dept1_aniosbgis |
| 6     | Rachel   | dept3_xwukpgbtr |
+-------+----------+-----------------+
```

2.Bonuses Table

```
+---------------+-------+
| department    | Bonus |
+---------------+-------+
| dept1_finance | 40000 |
| "dept2_hr"    | 50000 |
| "dept3_tech"  | 60000 |
+---------------+-------+
```

I want to perform a join on the 2 tables based on the department name column which is the deptname column in employees and department column in bonuses.
My issue is that the department column has some rows where the names are enclosed in double quotes and some are not. I need to take substring of the department name and it can be done something like this -

```
substr(department,1,5)
```

But in case of double quotes , it has to be done like this

```
substr(department,2,5)
```

I want to write an if-else statement to perform the join. But I'm not able to construct the query.
I would prefer to use joins ( to maintain the same pattern as with the other tables I have ).
The output should look like -

```
+-------+-------+
| empno | bonus |
+-------+-------+
| 1     | 40000 |
| 2     | 50000 |
| 3     | 60000 |
| 4     | 40000 |
| 5     | 40000 |
| 6     | 60000 |
+-------+-------+
```

Please help me in framing the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function `TRIM()` to remove leading and trailing double quotes (if they exist) from `department`:

```
SELECT e.empno, b.bonus
FROM Employee e LEFT JOIN Bonuses b
ON LEFT(TRIM('"' FROM b.department), 5) = LEFT(e.deptname, 5)
```

This code works for [MySql](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b8eb36083ff99cee9af982708af0660f) and [Postgresql](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=62fd2928cb901ea5ff7f953bdf7098ea).

Comment: Hi , is there any documentation present for TRIM?

Comment: @DawsonSmith Check this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Just a question out of curiosity, if I just want to select department names from bonuses table, how can I use the trim function to achieve that?

Comment: @DawsonSmith like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=896346108a4988eaac7cbf0811c0cf64

Comment: @DawsonSmith Amazon redshift supports both TRIM and LEFT so I suppose it will work.

Answer (score 1):

one wya is to  join on both condition using `IN` :

```
select * 
from table1 t1
join tbale2 t2
on t1.deptname in (t2.department, substr(t2.department,2,5) )
```

Comment: But t1.deptname also has a 'random' suffix after the deptX. Change it to substr(t1.deptname, 1, 5) and t2.department to substr(t2.department, 1, 5) and it'll work.